# how to seamlessly show progress using dynamic json data using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi here i am trying to show the progress bar from dynamic data

**requirement** : get data from the dynamic json and need to call the api for every x seconds using set interval from 0 to 100 if it reaches 100 then we need to stop the progress & show the same progress in next page  or if user presses we need to stop the process .

NOte: Need to call dyanmic json for every x seconds

**what i did** :

i created a progress for every x seconds so below is the code

```
<div>

            <div class="container">
                    <hr>
                    <div class="progress" id="blips">
                      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar">
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <hr>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Stop</button>

            </div>


    </div>
```

**js**

```
var data = {
    timer: {
        "num": "95.6",
        "perfection": "20",
}
}
$(document).ready(function(){

   loadData();

  });

  function loadData(){
    var timerId = 0;
    var ctr=0;
    var max= data['timer']['perfection'];

    timerId = setInterval(function () {
      // interval function
      ctr++;
      $('#blips > .progress-bar').attr("style","width:" + ctr*max + "%");

      // max reached?
      if (ctr==max){
        clearInterval(timerId);
      }

    }, 500);


  }

  $('.btn-primary').click(function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  });
```

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you've written?

Comment: @showdev  i am not sure how to seamlessly show progress  and i need to call the json data for every x seconds and based on that i need to update the progress and upon reaching the 100 from json data it needs to stop. is there any  other way

Comment: How does that differ from what you've got coded? What specifically goes wrong? I see several potential issues, but I'm not sure which is yours. Are you using any CSS? Do you need help with AJAX? What do you mean by "call dyanmic json"? Maybe it would help to know your final goal.

Comment: @showdevif u see my post currently i am using object usually it will be from the api and for every 2 seconds i need to call that api so that i will get the progress value and based on the progress values i need to show the progress value like increasing manner and currently what i have done also same but that approach which  i followed is correct or not i am not sure the approach of mine is correct or not and if the progress reaches 100 then it has to stop and if it reaches it has to display in another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made couple of changes:

1. The variable `data` should be declared inside

   `function loadData() {...}`

   or passed in as an argument
2. The jquery statement to set progress-bar width should be

   `$('#blips > .progress-bar').css("width", ctr + "%");`

With this changes, it works. See the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rahulsalvi2k7/eapgd4rc/11/

Comment: if i use the dynamic values i mean the json value "perfection": "20", may start at 0 and for every 2 seconds i will call the api and can i update the value also in the progress bar right ?

Comment: Why not call API every 2 seconds & update progressbar with response value in `setInterval()` ?

Comment: instead of static json object next i will use api and from that i will grab those values and update the progress bar so that is fine right

Comment: Yes as long as the setInterval loop gets updated values. It should be fine